# Get negative or positive numbers from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring

I wanted to query only the number from a string. This works perfect only in to extract a positive integer value. Apparently it takes out the - out of negative integers.

For example, executing these two gives the same output 10, but I expected -10 in the 2nd case.

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '10th'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@column, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @column), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @column + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    @column) + 1)  

DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '-10th'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@column, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @column), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @column + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    @column) + 1)
```

When I make the start part -ve, and replaced the +1 on the length part of the substring with +5, it retrieves negative values when expected. However, it leaves part of the string when the value is positive.

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '-10th'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@column, - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @column), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @column + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    @column) + 5)  

DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '-10th'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@column, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @column), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @column + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    @column) + 5)
```

I could apply a CASE statement to query interchanbly though like:

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '10th'
SELECT CASE WHEN @column like '%-%' THEN 
 SUBSTRING(@column, - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @column), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @column + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    @column) + 5)  
ELSE SUBSTRING(@column, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @column), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @column + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    @column) + 1)  END
```

But I was wondering if there is a simple work around.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

This might be worth a try. The ISNULL/NULLIF combination handles rows without letters. The SUBSTRING with 0 as starting point prevents errors from negative lengths.

```
SELECT SomeValue, ISNULL( NULLIF( SUBSTRING( SomeValue, 0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9-]%', SomeValue)),''), SomeValue)
FROM (VALUES('10th'),('-10th'),
            ('10'),('-10'),
            ('1st'),('-1st'),
            ('1'),('-1'),
            ('108th'), ('-108th'), 
            ('108'), ('-108'))x(SomeValue);
```

Comment: Good addition with NULLIF

Comment: Thanks. That's a trick I learned a while ago from Jeff Moden and his tests on the DelimitedSplit8K. I realize that my code is very similar to yours, but I swear that I didn't copy anything. We were just thinking alike.

Comment: Even if you did, you improved it, hence my +1

Answer (score 1):

If it always ends with two letters, like `th` or `nd` then you can just use `left` and `len`.

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '-10th'

DECLARE @column VARCHAR(20) = '10th'
select left(@column,len(@column) - 2)
```

Otherwise, you could look for the first non-numeric, starting with the second digit. This would account for any range of numbers, with anything after them.

```
declare @table table (mycolumn varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('10th'),
('-10th'),
('2nd'),
('-2nd'),
('104234thdsfasdf'),
('-104234thdsfasdf')
select 
    substring(mycolumn,1,patindex('%[^0-9]%',right(mycolumn,len(mycolumn) -1)))
from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
substring(@column, patindex('%[0-9-]%', @column), patindex('%[0-9-][^0-9]%', @column) - patindex('%[0-9-]%', @column) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
PATINDEX('%[^-,^0-9%',@column)
```

This should include any negative numbers

Comment: This just retrieves 0. Can you please write the complete line? Thanks.